# How to sync folder with Vagrant in Windows?

Tags: windows, vagrant

Using Vagrant 1.9.2 on Windows 10.

Installed rsync by `chololatey`:

```
C:\> choco install rsync
```

The `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  ...
  config.vm.synced_folder "data", "/vagrant"
  ...
end
```

Here want to sync `data` folder under the current path to `/vagrant` path in Vagrant. When login to Vagrant and make a `test` file under `/vagrant` path, check from Windows `data` folder, there exists nothing. So the file didn't synced. Why? How to sync?

---

## Edit

Started vagrant today, got new issue:

```
There was an error when attempting to rsync a synced folder.
Please inspect the error message below for more info.

Host path: /c/Users/me/data/
Guest path: /vagrant
Command: "rsync" "--verbose" "--archive" "--delete" "-z" "--copy-links" "--chmod=ugo=rwX" "--no-perms" "--no-owner" "--no-group" "--rsync-path" "sudo rsync" "-e" "ssh -p 2222 -o LogLevel=FATAL   -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i 'C:/Users/me/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key'" "--exclude" ".vagrant/" "/c/Users/me/data/" "vagrant@127.0.0.1:/vagrant"
Error: rsync: change_dir "/c/Users/me/data" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1178) [sender=3.1.2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `nfs` type to resolve the problem:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "data", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"
```

Comment: but... `NFS folders do not work on Windows hosts. Vagrant will ignore your request for NFS synced folders on Windows.`

Comment: This is old, but it snot the correct answer. As mentioned above, Windows does not support the NFS type. See https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/docs/synced-folders/nfs

Answer (score 2):

I used "generic/ubuntu2204" as a box, for some reason "/vagrant" folder doesn't exist.

I manage to get synced folder work with windows with this line :

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/vagrant/data"
```

Where "." is my vagrant directory with the Vagrantfile and "/home/vagrant/data" is where I want files on VM to be. My "data" folder was primary created. I don't know if you really have to create it first.